# How we can merge same row with exact count using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have output like this:

```
number      pd_team  rating         att_attorney      law_firm                  patent_developer
496486      Networks  Auto              Desai           Guntin                      Wade Walker     
520859      Networks  Auto              Snyder          Hanley                      Wade Walker 
449269      Networks  Auto              Silverman       Akerman                     Wade Walker 
526112      Networks  Auto              Chang           Amin; Turocy                Wade Walker 
558843      Networks  Auto              Silverman       Baker Botts;                Wade Walker 
403805      Networks  Auto              Chang           Baker Hostetler             Wade Walker     
264896      Networks  Auto              Desai           Fay Kaplun & Marcin;        Wade Walker 
228780      Networks  Auto              Desai           Jackson Walker;             Wade Walker     
534337      Networks  Auto              Chang           Myers Bigel                 Wade Walker 
174237      Networks  Auto              Desai           Scott P. Zimmerman;         Dylan Reid  
441658      Networks  Auto - CON        Desai           Toler Law Group PC          Wade Walker 
498561      Networks  Auto - CON        Chang           Tong; Rea; Bentley          Wade Walker
452380      Networks  Auto              Chang           Workman Nydegger            Wade Walker
```

The above table is output of an MySQL query what I want actual output is:

count of every field I.e

```
Network(13)
Auto(11)
Auto-CON(2)
Desai(5)
Snyder(1)
Silverman(2)
Chang(5)
same with other like wade walker(12)
```

Here is my MySQL query in which there can be multiple entry of filtes and all goes with AND.

```
SELECT number,salesforce_data.pd_team,salesforce_data.law_firm, salesforce_data.pd_team, salesforce_data.att_attorney,salesforce_data.patent_developer,salesforce_data.rating,salesforce_data.law_firm,salesforce_data.level1_taxonomy FROM application_data INNER JOIN salesforce_data on application_data.application_number= salesforce_data.sf_application_number WHERE salesforce_data.pd_team In ("Networks") AND salesforce_data.ip_manager_rating IN ("Auto","Auto - CON") AND salesforce_data.status="Filed"
```

Snapshot:
[image: ot]

Comment: what is meaning of Network(13)? Explain your question.

Comment: Is there a known/set limit to the different column values eg can patent_developer only contain the values Wade Walker and Dylan Reid? AND you want the output as a single column?

Comment: @SantoshVishwakarma - Count of row i.e wahtever I had writing query it gives above data in which Network count is 13.

Comment: @vikash you don't have a column called Network and none of of the columns contain a value of Network?

Comment: @P.Salmon - I mean to say there is a column pd_team contain value which is Network and there count is 13. Because there is one value which is network .
Suppose if pd_team contain another value like community then pd_team value count is Network(12) and community(1)

Comment: I think you want distinct count of cell value. Am I right Vikash?

Comment: @SantoshVishwakarma - yes

Comment: Let me clear this with an example
https://www.myntra.com/sports-wear?f=Brand%3AHRX%20by%20Hrithik%20Roshan%3A%3ACategories%3ATrack%20Pants&rf=Discount%20Range%3A50.0_100.0_50.0%20TO%20100.0

Please visit above link there is a Categories in left side contain the count of difrrent field in bracket() whenever it's apply another filter chnages it's count.

Same goes in my case there are multiple filter with above mentioned column and I want to show every filter output in bracket. Same like given link

Comment: Don't send people off to external links - especially when those links are hidden in comments. Instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query   and edit your question accordingly (although I very much suspect that the answer I've provided, while incomplete, will get you some way along)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with this...

```
SELECT number entity
     , 'pd_team'  attribute 
     , pd_team value
  FROM my_table
 UNION
SELECT number
     , 'rating'  attribute 
     , rating value
  FROM my_table
 UNION ...
```

Deriving the results from this would be trivial

Comment: Strawberry - Not working in my case, did you get my problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select t1.name Value, count(t1.name) Count from(
    select pd_team from Table
    union all
    select rating from Table
    union all
    select att_attorney from Table
    union all
    select law_firm from Table
    union all
    select patent_developer from Table) t1 group by t1.name;
```

Comment: @Vikash Try and inform me. Your requirement is fulfilled or not.

Comment: I will let you know.

Comment: Santosh - It's not solved my problem I had clearly given an example of myntra filters and shown dynamic count which changes whenever we applied any filter, same problem occur with me.

Comment: Santosh - I have attached a snapshot for your reference.